# Mapping node_modules folder in Angular 2

Tags: angular, npm, mapping, node-modules

I have this structure of folders in my Angular 2 App and when I import 'MultiselectDropdownModule' in line 23, I get error "Not found".
How can do the mapping with node_modules folder and avoid the absolute path?

[image]

Comment: The MultiselectDropdownModule might not have an export member. You can used `require()` to include them in your code.

Comment: U have used this module https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect right ?
Make sure that this module is installed properly.
check in node modules folder,
import { MultiselectDropdownModule } from 'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/src/multiselect-dropdown';
 is correct & There are no errors there.

Comment: @ParthGhiya i did it and I got this error:
http://localhost:3000/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/src/multiselect-dropdown 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on a similar project with you.
It is totally working OK on my project. I import it the module at the xxx.module.ts (a sub module of the application).

`import {MultiselectDropdownModule} from 'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/src/multiselect-dropdown';`

maybe can your try angular/cli ? I'm sure the angualr/cli (webpack) running the plugin perfect.

[image]